# Azure Remote rendering error - EXEC : fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-ssa-cfg-jt-' in 'p2'

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality, azure-remote-rendering

I am trying to build Azure remote rendering unity showcase project. After unity build the output visual studio project upon building is giving below error, my Unity 3D version is 2019.4.29f and visual studio version is 2019:

> il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Il2CppTypeDefinitions.c
> 1>EXEC : fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-ssa-cfg-jt-' in 'p2'

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\ADO-Repo\MR\ARR\Unity\v2019\ARRShowcase\ARRApp\build\bin\ARM64\Release\GameAssembly.lib'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the compiler flags in the *Il2CppOutputProject* project contain an error. I generated the Showcase solution with Unity 2019.4.29f and see a similar flag `-d2ssa-cfg-jt-` in there.

You can check if the compiler flags in your generated solution contain `-ssa-cfg-jt-`, and if so try replacing that by `-d2ssa-cfg-jt-`.

To view the compiler flags in Visual Studio open the Properties of the *Il2CppOutputProject* project. Then go to the *NMake* page and edit the *Build Command Line* field. In my configuration `--compiler-flags="-d2ssa-cfg-jt-"` is right at the end: [Il2CppOutputProject Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So4O1.png).